# How do I convert 123 to 1,2,3 in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql

Is it possible to convert 123 to 1,2,3 in pl/sql?

is there any easy way to convert or add a comma between two numbers in pl/sql?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need PL/SQL for this. A `regexp_replace` will do it:

```
rtrim(regexp_replace('123','(\d)','\1,'),',')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.